# GLKView snapshot performance issue on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I need to retreive the screen image from the GLKView and resize it and send it to the network to feed a Led matrix. So with this requirement, I need to take a snapshot of the GLKView every 30 ms. 
The problem I encounter is that it takes around  150 ms on my iPad to proceed :

```
UIImage *snap = [(GLKView *)self.view snapshot] ;
```

I am looking for a quicker/better alternative to this snapshot method to retreive the screen capture.

Thanks for your help,
Regards,
Christophe.

Comment: Maybe you can get your answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261450/using-opengl-es-texture-caches-instead-of-glreadpixels-to-get-texture-data
Though I am not sure if "snapshot" already uses this method or "glReadPixels"

Comment: It seems a good idea, but I need much more "fluent" in iOS/Ojective C as there are very few example available.

Comment: I don't think there is anything faster then this. There has always been a problem getting the data from the GPU... The only thing that is left is to use a smaller resolution: Retina vs. non retina should increase performance by factor 4.