# glTexSubImage2D slow on ios7

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios7

I have a project where I need to update multiple areas of a texture and synchronise those areas into openGL every frame. I'm using openGL ES 2.0 with a project in xcode5 for iDevices.

To sync those texture changes I use glTexSubImage2D, potentially calling this function several hundred times per frame for small areas of the bound texture. This works fast enough for my needs when testing on an iPhone4 running ios6.

When I test it on my iPad Mini Retina, running ios7, it stalls significantly.
The stalls show up in mach_msg_trap from three functions called under glTexSubImage2D.

Unfortunately I can't post images of the profile (due to a lack of reputation points), but the three functions are called from agxuBlitRender, taking up a combined 86.1% of the CPU:
agxuCreateRenderTarget (38.2%)
SubmitPackets (25.5%)
agxuReleaseAllRenderTargets (16.2%)

I appreciate mach_msg_trap just means the thread is spinning whilst waiting, but I cannot determine what it's waiting for, from the profiler.

I was initially wondering whether it might be rebuilding mip-maps or some other process that ios7 forces. I've not got mipmaps turned on, although according to the options in gl.h, I might not have much of a choice (all the TextureMinFilters are mipmap orientated, even though I set it to GL_NEAREST, it might be defaulting to GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST if it considers GL_NEAREST invalid). The fact that the iPhone4 version uses the exact same code might not be the deciding factor if it deals with mipmapping under the hood.

Whilst I've tried just copying the entire texture once per frame, this becomes significantly slower with larger texture sizes, when the function twiddle32x32_32, deep in the heart of openGL, eats a large portion of the CPU per frame.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to update that many separate areas of a texture that many times per frame? Is this a texture atlas you're trying to rebuild each frame?

Comment: @BradLarson I have a particle system where many objects are gathered into larger blocks (or split again) for processing. When I gather their physical properties, I need to also gather their graphical ones, like four small cubes being gathered into one larger cube (and so on with larger and larger cubes). So I need to have the smaller entity's texels moved together to simplify into larger groups of texels, adjusting UVs as I go. I guess it is a form of texture atlas and there might be simpler (better understood) ways of doing it. If only it worked faster on Mini Retina than iPhone4 though :)

Answer (score 1):

glTexSubImage2D() is very slow on all devices that use PowerVR GPUs because of their deferred rendering tile-based design and because of the twiddling.  I'm more familiar with Android where you can get a virtual pointer to the texture and access the pixels directly by using EGL Image extensions.  This is typically 4x faster.  However, I have read that similar capabilities are available in iOS as well.  For example:

[Using OpenGL ES texture caches instead of glReadPixels to get texture data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261450/using-opengl-es-texture-caches-instead-of-glreadpixels-to-get-texture-data)

Comment: Thanks Clay, though that's very much for reading pixel data from the graphics side, rather than writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling glTexSubImage2D() "hundreds of times per frame" is really bad.  You should step back and ask yourself why you need to do that.  It will be slow on any platform, because GPUs aren't designed to support that.

What are you doing that requires texture updates at runtime?

If you must, one option is to keep a copy of the texture in main memory (as an array of BGRA or LUMINENCE pixels).  Perform your updates there.  Then upload it to the GPU with one call.  You should only upload at the beginning or end of the frame, to minimize the CPU stalling.  (The CPU will block a long time if the GPU is currently using that texture).

Comment: Sean, I appreciate what I'm doing is atypical and if it didn't work with my initial prototype, on less powerful hardware, I would have said "nice try, let's do something else". The fact it works perfectly quickly enough for my needs on iPhone4 and not on brand new hardware is my issue (with the exact same code and content). For the iPad I'm now uploading in one call to gTexlSubImage2D (with much CPU lost to twiddle32x32_32), whilst updating my iPhone4 with a call to gTexlSubImage2D for each texture change (at the same point in code) I'd like to know why this is necessary and avoid if possible.

Comment: To be specific, what I'm doing takes up < 1% of the CPU on iPhone4 even in the worst case. On iPad Mini Retina it takes up > 85% sitting in mach_msg_trap, whilst running at 1-2fps. In the same situation you'd probably like to know why too :)

Comment: @Drainboy - I'm not sure that CPU-based profiling of the functions you're using will give you a very accurate representation of true performance on iOS devices, because of the deferred nature of the PowerVR GPUs. You almost have to look at the whole frame rendering time from beginning to presentation to screen to get any meaningful data about rendering performance. However, that retina iPad mini you have has an A7 chip in it, and the latest version of Xcode has a new shader profiler which can give you better profiling information. You might want to try that out here.